# Shared (static) classes with events in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, static

Here is an example of what I would do in Visual Basic:

```vb
Public Class Class1
    Public Shared WithEvents Something As New EventClass

    Public Shared Sub DoStuff() Handles Something.Test

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class EventClass
    Public Event Test()
End Class
```

How do I do this in C#?

I know there is not a `Handles` clause in C# so I need some function that is called and assign the event handlers there. However, since it's a shared class, there is no constructor; I must put it somewhere outside of a function.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static constructor...

```
static readonly EventClass _something;

static Class1()
{
  _something = new EventClass();
  _something.Test += DoStuff;
}

static void DoStuff()
{
}
```

Comment: Just remember that static constructors are not automatically called when program starts like in c/c++. They are called when the static class is accessed for the first time in you code same goes for all static member variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
public static class Class1 {
  private static EventClass something;
  public static EventClass Something {
    get { return something; }
  }
  static Class1 {
    something = new Class1();
    something.Test += DoStuff;
  }

  public static void DoStuff() {
    ...
  }
}
```